# Using Serverless, how do you set a Lambda function's authorizer to a Cognito User Pool from the Resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, serverless-framework, serverless

In my serverless.yml, I have a Lambda function and I want to set it's authorizer to a Cognito User Pool that I have declared in the Resources section down below. I've seen examples where the authorizer is set to `aws_iam` but that seems wrong. Any help would be amazing :)

I'm thinking I need to set the authorizer's ARN to the Pool's ARN, but how do I get that? Or is that even correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in another answer, hard coding the ARN works. So intuitively, you might think something like this would work:

```
    authorizer:
      arn: 
        Fn::GetAtt: [UserPool, Arn]
```

Sadly, it does not.  It looks like *Serverless* bumps your `arn` up against a couple of regular expressions to determine whether you're pointing at a lambda or a user pool.  This approach doesn't seem to play nicely with approaches using things like `Ref`, `Fn::Join`, or `Fn::GetAtt`

---

As of [Serverless 1.27.3](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases/tag/v1.27.3) (which was released since this question was asked), there is [a workaround of sorts](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/pull/4197) available.

Essentially you declare your Authorizer in your `resources` section, instead of letting *Serverless* auto-magically create it for you.  Then you use the new `authorizerId` key in your `functions` section to point at this authorizer.  A minimal example:

```
service: sls-cognitotest

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /api/{proxy+}
          integration: lambda
          authorizer: 
            type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
            authorizerId: { Ref: MyApiGatewayAuthorizer }
resources:
  Resources:
    CognitoUserPoolGeneral:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: general
    MyApiGatewayAuthorizer: 
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
      Properties: 
        AuthorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 10
        IdentitySource: method.request.header.Authorization
        Name: MyCognitoAuthorizer
        RestApiId: 
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        Type: COGNITO_USER_POOLS
        ProviderARNs: 
          - {"Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:cognito-idp:", {Ref: "AWS::Region"}, ":", {Ref: "AWS::AccountId"}, ":userpool/", Ref: CognitoUserPoolGeneral]]}
```

---

It isn't great, but it's better than having to hard code the user pool ARN into your template.

Comment: Yikes, ProviderARNs is a rough combination of crazy, but whatever does the trick I suppose :P

Comment: I am trying a similiar YAML but I am getting:
Please provide either an authorizer name or ARN
Serverless 1.25.0

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ? https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers

Example:

```
AFunctionName:
  handler: src/index.handler
  description: desc
  environment: ${file(environment.yml)}
  events:
    - http:
        method: any
        path: /api/{proxy+}
        authorizer:
          arn: arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:123456:userpool/eu-west-1_123456
```

Comment: No, actually, I won't have the ARN because the Resource will be created by Serverless. It's close, but what I'm looking for is the syntax to get Serverless to insert WHATEVER the ARN or other kind of Resource Identifier ends up being when it creates the Cognito instance.